# TypeORM OneToMany relationship in the same entity

Tags: orm, entity, typeorm

I am struggling with creating a OneToMany relationship with the same entity. Is it possible in TypeORM?

Assuming I have an entity:

```
export class X {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToMany( what here???? ) 
  tests: X[];
}
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
export class X {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToMany(type => X, x => x.belongsToTest ) 
  tests: X[];

  @ManyToOne(type => X, x => x.tests)
  belongsToTest: X;
}
```